# How to express as Matrix operations?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, octave

I have a matrix `A`:

```
1 3 1
7 5 2
4 3 7
8 2 1
3 9 6
4 5 2
```

and a matrix `B`:

```
2 9 1
4 3 8
9 7 3
4 4 2
6 5 7
2 9 2
```

I want to compute `C`:

```
1*2+3*9+1*1
7*4+5*3+2*8
4*9+3*7+7*3
8*4+2*4+1*2
3*6+9*5+6*7
4*2+5*9+2*2
```

How can I express this purely using matrix operations? I realize I can do this using `.` versions but I am interested in pure matrix operations. For example, when I have two vectors  `x` and `y`, I vastly prefer `x'*y` over `sum(x.*y)`. Hence I am interested in how to do the above also using matrix operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use vector operators, you can get the same result by performing a matrix multiplication with the transpose of the **second** multiplicand (otherwise you'll get a 3x3 result, in this case), and then extracting the diagonal.

Like so: `C = diag(A * B')`

I'm not quite sure how Octave optimizes this, but it appears to only be *slightly* slower than the element-wise approach. (at least, for this data set)

```
function test(func, n, a, b)
    for i = 1:n
        func(a, b);
    endfor
endfunction

octave> tic; test(@(a, b) sum(a.*b, 2), 100000, A, B); toc
Elapsed time is 2.843 seconds.

octave> tic; test(@(a, b) diag(a*b'), 100000, A, B); toc
Elapsed time is 3.2 seconds.
```

**CAUTION**: A real life problem shows this to be *far* slower than the element-wise approach:

```
octave:100> size(yy)
ans =

   5000     10

octave:101> size(expected)
ans =

   5000     10

octave:102> tic; diag(yy * expected'); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.5447 seconds.
octave:103> tic; sum(yy .* expected, 2); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.0016899 seconds.
```

Comment: thanks, that seems like it. i wonder if octave optimizes it internally to do an efficient computation (?)

Comment: @EitanT: Because he wants to compute the **sums** of the rows of the **products** of the elements in the two matrices. In other words, he was a vector of length N, where N is the number of rows in the original matrices. If you don't take the diagonal of the product matrix, you get an NxN result.

Comment: thank you both; i'll accept this as a an authoritative answer; it is also consistent with the opinion of the folks from math.stackexchange

Comment: octave:100> size(yy)
ans =

   5000     10

octave:101> size(expected)
ans =

   5000     10

octave:102> tic; diag(yy * expected'); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.5447 seconds.
octave:103> tic; sum(yy .* expected, 2); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.0016899 seconds.

Comment: my actual problem showed this to be far slower. i've attempted to edit the answer with the info. this is still the correct answer, but the performance difference must be noted by anybody adopting it.

Comment: @agks mehx, Yes, it's clearly slower because you're doing a whole bunch of dot products you don't need, then throwing them away with the `diag`. `sum(A.*B,2)`, on the other hand, is doing only exactly what it needs.  The latter is about 30% faster on my machine.

Comment: @ChrisA. yes, hopefully octave/matlab will someday optimize computations much like relational databases optimize queries. the optimization process is very close in this case since the `.*` is a merge join which would be expressed in the query as a cartesian product, i. e. `A*B'` btw, the % difference can be totally misleading when the order of the algorithms are different because you can make the % difference as large as you want by increasing input size. and if the % difference happens to be small it may be an accident of the input size.

Answer (score 4):

You should use vector operations

```
C = sum( A .* B , 2 );
```

The `.*` operator multiplies matrices value-by-value, while `sum( <matrix> , 2 )` sums along the rows of a matrix inside the first parameter.

Comment: thank you for your response, but please note the last para of my question.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, this is about as good as it can get. These are still vector operations and are very fast.

Comment: yes, i understand; but a sophisticated implementation could effectively do this as an optimization of a pure matrix operations specification.

Comment: -1: You can do it faster without the sum: use matrix multiplication on the transpose instead of elementwise.

Comment: @EitanT Read the question. You'll get a different answer if you multiply by transpose.

Comment: @EitanT No. (MxN) * (NxK) = (MxK).

Comment: @Phonon voithos presents a more efficient solution with the `diag`. In your solution, each matrix element is used _twice_: once with matrix elementwise multiplication, and once in the summation. In voithos' solution each element is computed _once_, and `diag` just turns it into a vector.

Comment: @Phonon, i'll accept the other answer since i did not want to do `.*` and stated that. however, i appreciate your providing a correct answer (in fact, more efficient per benchmark in other answer), so you have definitely my upvote :)

Comment: @EitanT, i appreciate your robust critique. i do like the diag solution and i hope in the future octave/matlab can optimize it so it performs as good as phonon's answer.

Comment: @agksmehx @Phonon I measured the `diag` approach vs. this one in **MATLAB** and matrix multiplication (plus `diag`, which costs virtually nothing) is by ~50% faster than by using elementwise multiplication and summing.

Comment: @EitanT, could you please double-check? -- in octave `diag` is vastly slower. please note that there is an order of magnitude difference in time complexity in the naive implementation that octave has. so, the difference shows up only when the number of rows is large. `diag` is `O(n^2)` whereas `sum(.*)` is `O(n)` assuming number of columns is relatively very small. in my real life case of `5000x10` matrices `diag` on octave was `250x` slower!

Comment: @EitanT, an easy way to verify: `octave> tic; diag(repmat(magic(10), 500, 1)*repmat(magic(10), 500, 1)'); toc;` gives "Elapsed time is 0.549546 seconds." and `octave> tic; sum(repmat(magic(10), 500, 1).*repmat(magic(10), 500, 1), 2); toc;` gives "Elapsed time is 0.0153179 seconds."

Comment: @agksmehx I tested it on MATLAB, not Octave, but whatever suits you. If you find this one consistently faster, I will remove the downvote and upvote instead.

Comment: @EitanT, a better test since it does not repeatedly compute `magic`: is`octave> A = repmat(magic(10), 500, 1); octave> B = repmat(magic(5), 1000, 2); octave> tic; diag(A*B'); toc;` gives "Elapsed time is 0.492 seconds." and `octave> tic; sum(A.*B, 2); toc;` gives "Elapsed time is 0.00171 seconds."

Comment: @Phonon My downvote is locked, but if agksmehx finds your solution to be consistently faster you deserve an upvote and I will stand corrected. Edit your answer somehow and I will change my vote to an upvote instead.